# Check if something is a member in a nested list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, nested, member

I want to check if `x` is a member of a nested list, so that

```
member(x,[a,b,[c,d],[e,[f,g],[x,i]]])
```

returns `True`, and `False` if there is no `x`. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply expand the normal recursive `member` definition by adding a clause that checks if the item is a member of the first element:

```
member(X, [X|_]).                 %X is first element
member(X, [L|_]) :- member(X, L). %X is member of first element
member(X, [_|T]) :- member(X, T). %X is member of tail
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [flatten/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=flatten/2) to get all elements onto the same level and then use ordinary member:

```
?- flatten([a,b,[c,d],[e,[f,g],[x,i]]],Xs), member(x,Xs).
Xs = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, x, i] ;
false.
```

and if x is not contained:

```
?- flatten([a,b,[c,d],[e,[f,g],[y,i]]],Xs), member(x,Xs).
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

By this you find the member in a simple list. ( _ ) -> Singleton Variable

```
//Base Case

member(X, [X | _ ]).
member(X, [ _ | T]) :- member(X, T).
```

By this you find the member in a nested list using the defination of a simple list:

```
nestedListMember(X, [H | T]) :- 
    member(X,H); 
    nestedListMember(X,T). %Recursive call looking in the tail
nestedListMember(X,[T]) :- 
    nestedListMember(X,T). %You look for all the subsequent cases
```